# Arduino + ULN2003 + stepper motors?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a need to control 2 stepper motors independently and a set of three 4" fans with variable DC voltage from 0-12vdc (not pwm).

I read an article about using the Arduino Uno and a ULN2003 chip to control a stepper motor and I wonder if the Arduino will control the two stepper motors I need to control (not at the same time). Icing on the cake would be to run the 3 fans.

Can this be done using a single Arduino and if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Greg

--